# In Lua, should a functions arguements be (re)localised in the function?

Tags: function, lua, local-variables

Consider:

```
function function_name(var_one, var_two)
    var_one = var_two 
    return var_one
end 

print( function_name("string_one", "string_two") )
```

As appose to `local var_one = var_two`

Is `var_one` now a global variable or is it still in the functions local scope?

Should `local var_one` be used or is it already in the scope?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? It's hard to tell what it is this should be doing. And without that, there's nothing to say that what you have there is in any way wrong.

Comment: Edited to explain that I am asking whether `var_one` would become global or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no need for this. The name `var_one` is already local. You are simply wiping out the original value. You must use `_G.var_one` if you wish to explicitly refer to the global.

Answer (score 0):

The argument is a local variable (already).

When you reference it (the assignment), it looks for a lexically scoped variable with that name. It finds the local variable and uses it.

It's this local variable that becomes an "upvalue" (a non-local variable) if the function is a closure.

If it doesn't find the local variable, it instead performs a global lookup. If you want to force a global lookup, you just manually go into the globals table, since that's what a global lookup is.

If you change the assignment of the variable to declare it as local, you're actually creating a new local variable, lexically scoped, which is distinct from the argument, but hiding it lexically.